# How can I check whether user is currently using the audio seekbar?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an HTML audio player like this:

```
<audio  id="audioPlayer" controls>
    <source src="test.mp3">
</audio>
```

I want to display some images in sync the audio file, including when the user is moving the seekbar.
However, I can't find a way to check whether user is currently using the audio seekbar.

I have tried to use the `timeupdate`event with no success: the code below works only when user seeks back in time.

```
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
var lastUpdateTime;

audioPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {update();});

function update() {
    if ( audioPlayer.currentTime - lastUpdateTime < 0 )
       console.log("seeking");
    lastUpdateTime = audioPlayer.currentTime;
}
```

I am looking for something working on "recent" browsers (e.g. IE10+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but works:

**Version with jQuery:**

```
var $audio = $( '#myAudio' );
var onPause = false;

// Pause event helps us to know is player playing or not
$audio.on( 'pause', function() {
  onPause = true;

  setTimeout(function() {

      onPause = false;
  });
});

$audio[0].on( 'timeupdate', function(e) {

  // trick to get current pause state
  setTimeout(function(){

     // checks if player paused and not last timeupdate event call
     if ( $audio[0].paused && !onPause ) {

        // Fire event then user is changing seek bar
        $audio.trigger( 'userSeeking' );
      }
  });
});

$audio.on( 'userSeeking', function(){
  // do some magic
});
```

**Version with pure javascript:**

```
var audio = document.getElementById( 'myAudio' );
var onPause = false;
var seek = false;

// Pause event helps us to know is player playing or not
audio.addEventListener( 'pause', function(e) {
  onPause = true;

  setTimeout(function() {

      onPause = false;
  });
});

audio.addEventListener( 'timeupdate', function(e) {

  // trick to get current pause state
  setTimeout(function(){

     seek = false;

     // checks if player paused and not last timeupdate event call
     if ( $audio[0].paused && !onPause ) {

        seek = true;
        // Fire event then user is changing seek bar
     }

     // or you can return current state of seeking here
  });
});
```

And here is working example ( codepen using jQuery version ):

http://codepen.io/GomatoX/pen/ZYpWbN

Comment: Well, I don't understand your answer. Your solution displays the current play time. It doesn't indicate whether the user is moving the seekbar around.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I got it working according to my needs. I've updated your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNwpPy. I suggest that you modify the code in your answer accordingly and that you add some explanation to make your answer clearer for other people.